# Blender images rendering w/out color

Tags: blender

When I render an image in blender it just comes out black even when I color it.
This [stool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT6Kt.png) is supposed to be different materials but instead this.
Please help I have tried things from at least ten different sites and none have worked.
Also using Cycles Render.

Comment: probably get more purchase on blender.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to add light to the scene. If this doesn't work, you can link the file here so I can help you. Good luck!